# link size and color (nameref)

Tags: hyperref, color

I create a link with `\nameref`:

```
\section*{\Huge {\color{DarkRed}This is a headline}}
\label{sec:headline}
```

When I reference to this section with

```
\nameref{sec:headline}
```

The link is displayed the same size (Huge) and color (Dark Red) as the section title.

The hyperref setup is:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

How can I avoid that link color and size are taken from the section setup. I want to keep them independent from one another.

EDIT: Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\nameref{sec:headline}

\newpage
\section*{\Huge {\color{red}This is a headline}}
 \label{sec:headline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't use any font commands as an argument of `\section`!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the appearance in general, then use a more powerful class (`scrartcl`/`KOMA-Script`, `memoir`, …) or a package (`sectsty`, …):

- Then you have a clean markup.
- It also works for the table of contents or the page headers.

### Package `gettitlestring`

Package `hyperref` uses package `nameref`. Since 2009/12/08 it uses package `gettitlestring` to get and process the title data. With method `expand` commands can be redefined via `\GetTitleStringDisableCommands` similar to `hyperref`'s `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` for bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}[2009/12/08]% uses package `gettitlestring'

\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{%
  \let\Huge\empty % disables \Huge
  % or \renewcommand*{\Huge}{}%
  \let\color\@gobble % disables \color{...}
  % or \renewcommand*{\color}[1]{}%
}

\begin{document}

\nameref{sec:headline}

\newpage
\section*{\Huge {\color{red}This is a headline}}
 \label{sec:headline}

\end{document}
```

However, only expandable redefinitions can be used. LaTeX's scanning for optional arguments does not work.

Comment: In my opinion you has provided a workaround instead of a "clear" solution. With the mentioned classes of KOMA you can set the font eg. by `addkomafont` what should be the correct answer here (This is my personal opinion)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The question is not clear, if a solution for *all* sections headers is needed or if only a particular `\section` is affected. Right at the beginning I have given the general solutions. The documentation of the classes and packages should be sufficient and there are probably quite a few "duplicate" questions. However I have some doubts that the workaround solution, which is useful for some circumstances, has already hit common knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly with komascript it is fairly easy:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

 \setkomafont{section}{\Huge \color{red}}                                                                                                                 
\begin{document}

\nameref{sec:headline}

\newpage
\section*{This is a headline}
\label{sec:headline}

\end{document}
```